# EF Code First and confirmation fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, automapper

I am creating a user class and want to add a ConfirmPassword field.  Since I don't have this field in my database how do I handle it?  I am also using AutoMapper, do I need to do anything to handle this extra field, for example to tell the mapper to ignore this field?

I have my user class here, and I have just added NotMapped attribute in the buddy class. Is this all that I would need to do? Or is there any additional coding that is required to handle this scenario?

```
public partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
        //this.DateCreated = DateTime.Now; //set default value
        Roles = new HashSet<Role>();
    }

    public ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; } //many to many relationship

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }

    //foreign key
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    //navigation properties
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }

    //foreign key
    public int LanguageId { get; set; }
    //navigation properties
    public virtual Language Language { get; set; }

    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public long FacebookId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}

//buddy class, validation in here because not supported in Fluent API
//test in ie
//MetadataType decorated class
[MetadataType(typeof(UserMetadata))]
public partial class User
{
}

//Metadata type
internal sealed class UserMetadata
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Remote("IsUsernameAvailable", "Validation")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [DisplayName("Username")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CountryId { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int LanguageId { get; set; } 
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public long FacebookId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}
```

}

Edit : Here is my corresponding DTO class :

```
public class UserDTO
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string CountryName { get; set; }
        public string LanguageName { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public long FacebookId { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `ConfirmPassword` field should be defined on your view model class, not on your domain model object that is tracked by Entity Framework. Since this value is never stored into the database it shouldn't even be part of your domain model.

This property should be defined only on your view model class, the one that is mapped to your Create Account view. You don't need to do any special steps with AutoMapper to handle this field, since it should not be part of your domain model => it will be ignored when AutoMapper is mapping between your CreateUserViewModel and your User model.

Comment: I am using DTOs and buddy classes for validation.  How would I implement your suggestion, as the ConfirmPassword property needs to be in the class as it is validated.

Comment: No, the ConfirmPassword property, as I've already explained in my answer, must be located only on the view model. You will then validate this view model. Once the view model has been validated you could use AutoMapper to construct your DTO or domain model or whatever you are calling it from the view model. But once again, the ConfirmPassword field has meaning only on the view model. If you have put it in some other layers of your models, I am afraid that you are doing it wrong.

Comment: I am a bit confused with Model vs View Model....I have my model that interacts with the database, and then a DTO which is used on the UI side.  Where does View Model come into this scenario?

Comment: The NotMapped attribute means that I can put the property into my validation buddy class but leave it out of my model, isn't this the solution to this?

Comment: The `NotMapped` attribute is an Entity Framework specific attribute. As I have already stated in my answer the ConfirmPassword property should be defined on your view model and not on your domain model. View models should not have any persistent specific attributes on them. There are many tutorials out there about the usage of view models. Here's one: http://www.rachelappel.com/use-viewmodels-to-manage-data-amp-organize-code-in-asp.net-mvc-applications